# how to write this javascript function in coffeescript (ajax callbacks)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript

```
jQuery(function($) {
  // create a convenient toggleLoading function
  var toggleLoading = function() { $("#loading").toggle() };

  $("#new_post")
    .bind("ajax:loading",  toggleLoading)
    .bind("ajax:complete", toggleLoading)
    .bind("ajax:success", function(event, data, status, xhr) {
      $("#response").html(data);
    });
});
```

this is my js function (or [Simone Carletti's](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/)) and I want to transform it to coffeescript, I am having trouble with the last two callbacks, though.

My coffeescript looks like this

```
jQuery ->
    $("#new_post")
    .bind("ajax:loading",  toggleLoading)
    .bind("ajax:complete", toggleLoading)
    .bind("ajax:success", (event, data, status, xhr) ->
        alert(data)
    .bind("ajax:failure", (event, data, status, xhr) ->
        alert(data)
```

but I am getting an `Error: unclosed INDENT on line 21`

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is simply that you have mismatched parentheses. The line

```
.bind("ajax:success", (event, data, status, xhr) ->
    alert(data)
```

never closes the `.bind` call. Change your code to

```
jQuery ->
    $("#new_post")
    .bind("ajax:loading",  toggleLoading)
    .bind("ajax:complete", toggleLoading)
    .bind("ajax:success", (event, data, status, xhr) ->
        alert(data))
    .bind("ajax:failure", (event, data, status, xhr) ->
        alert(data))
```

and it'll work just fine.

Comment: pretty show indetion is right, are you sure the last 4 lines of my coffeescript are correct? I wonder if i need any parenthesis or something...

Comment: Sorry, I assumed a tab/spaces issue, but on second glance it was a parens issue. I've changed my answer.